# How to automatically blend images to create realistic composites (java)

Tags: java, android, opencv, blend

I have two images - background & foreground, having different lighting conditions and colour tones. Each of them contains a person. Also i have an alpha mask for the person in foreground image. I want to blend the person (cropped out using mask) from the foreground with the background image so that the final image looks as if the person in the foreground was standing next to person in background(i.e realistic composite blending).I already have the segmentation mask and i'am able to get the cropped out person from foreground image.It looks like we need to ensure proper illumination, saturation and colour matching to obtain a natural blended feel.It seems, we can easily do that using photoshop manually([link1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fgB_oO4xt1A),[link2](https://youtu.be/TZnXQZWejPg)). How can achieve similar results programmatically, given two random background and foreground images with person?

The following are the approaches i tried; but each of them have certain issues  and  works only with certain types of images.

1.OpenCV Seamless clone - Works pretty well for plane and similar contrast images.Issues:- heavy, smudging, cannot be generalised for all types of images.

2.Photorealistic style transfer - Works great; but its heavy, needs special training and works only with few class of images. Still artefacts may be present.

3.Fast Color Transfer (pyimagesearch)- Works for plane background. Background color averaging causes colours to be spill over to image roi and thus loses its natural feel.

Also tried normal alpha blending, laplacian blending, histogram matching etc. Additionally, experimented with techniques like CLAHE, gamma correction, histogram equalisation, edge blending etc to adjust and improve the output of blending. Unfortunately, none of these combinations gave the desired result.(NB:-The output should not ideally look as if a layer is stacked or pasted on top of background image).i.e we need a seamless natural blend.

Is this possible only using some AI models or is there any light weight methods for performing automatic image composting in java, using some standard libraries (should work adaptively for any two images in general)?

We are trying to achieve something similar to the following methods:-

1. https://people.csail.mit.edu/yichangshih/portrait_web/
2. https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.09828
3. https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~kb/publications/egsr18_harmonization.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the answer..Here is the caffe implementaion of Deep Color Harmoniation: https://github.com/wasidennis/DeepHarmonization. It seems to a light weight network and works pretty fast. Still trying to figure out how to convert the same to a mobile friendly format like tensorflow lite ...

[image: Deep Color harmonization]

Hope it helps somebody ...